# Oracle Update Stored Proc not working from C# code

Tags: c#, oracle, stored-procedures

I have the following code:

```
try
        {
            conn.Open();
            OracleCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "collikx.webadmin.usp_update_license";
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("licenseSeqNo", OracleDbType.Int32, 30, 228, ParameterDirection.Input));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("thirdPartyId", OracleDbType.Int32, 30, 2, ParameterDirection.Input));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("licenseNumber", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 12, "tttttttttttt", ParameterDirection.Input));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("licenseState", OracleDbType.Char, 2, "CT", ParameterDirection.Input));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("licenseLevel", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 2, "E1", ParameterDirection.Input));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("licenseType", OracleDbType.Char, 2, "QQ", ParameterDirection.Input));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("cutTap", OracleDbType.Char, 1, "Y", ParameterDirection.Input));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("status", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 30, "NOTVALID", ParameterDirection.Input));
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            throw;
        }
        finally { conn.Close(); }
```

The stored proc is:

```
PROCEDURE usp_update_license( thirdPartyId integer,
                              licenseSeqNo integer,
                              licenseNumber VARCHAR2,
                              licenseState VARCHAR2,
                              licenseLevel VARCHAR2,
                              licenseType VARCHAR2,
                              cutTap VARCHAR2,
                              status VARCHAR2) AS
begin
  update CNTRCTR_LCNS_INFO
    set cntrctr_lcns_no = licenseNumber,
        lcns_st_cd = licenseState,
        certfn_level_type_cd = licenseLevel,
        cntrctr_type_cd = licenseType,
        cut_tap_authy_ind = cutTap,
        stat_type_nm = status
  where third_party_id = thirdPartyId and cntrctr_lcns_seq_no = licenseSeqNo
        ;
  COMMIT;
         EXCEPTION
          WHEN OTHERS THEN
          ROLLBACK;
          RAISE;
end usp_update_license;
```

When I execute this, nothing in the database changes. I know it's getting called from C# because if i comment out one of the parameter lines I get an error that there are not enout params. However, the value "QQ" for licenseType in the C# code should violate a FK contraint but I get no error telling me that. I have other stored procs called exactly the same way that work fine...

**I should note that executing the stored proc directly through sql developer works.**

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the parameters out of order:

switch

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("licenseSeqNo", OracleDbType.Int32, 30, 228, ParameterDirection.Input));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("thirdPartyId", OracleDbType.Int32, 30, 2, ParameterDirection.Input));
```

to

```
 cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("thirdPartyId", OracleDbType.Int32, 30, 2, ParameterDirection.Input));
 cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("licenseSeqNo", OracleDbType.Int32, 30, 228, ParameterDirection.Input));
```

You are not getting the where clause to match (binds by order by default)
in ODP you can change this .[BindByName](http://oradim.blogspot.com/2007/08/odpnet-tip-bind-variables-and.html) = True to overwrite the default BindByName =false

**EDIT**
You will want to 
`cmd.BindByName = True;`

(this defaults to FALSE and causes the confusion and problem!)

Comment: wow... never would have thought that they were binding by order... what the friggin point of the name? Anyways, whats the command to change it to bind by name, because i changed the order and it worked, but i would rather it bind by name.

Comment: nvm - i found it, it's under OracleCommand. Thanks so much your a life saver, now i can go home, rather than stay to work all day!

Comment: this one has caused me enough confusion that I tend to put them into order just to be really sure and it's the first thing I check for when I have a problem like this!

Comment: ya the defaulting to false is stupid. it just causes situations like this where there is no error, but it's not working correctly. I did actually at one point think that the wrong record might have gotten updated. Where the thirdPartyId and licenseSeqNo were the oposite of the one i wanted, but i could never replicate it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

May be the Where Clause is not matching...

Try executing the store procedure from Oracle itself.

Comment: On the exception block, try writing to an error log table.  If their are no entries then you can be sure that the problem is with  exception handling on C#.  If no errors on the log table then you can be sure that the update where clause failed.  Either way try to write the value of licenseSeqNo and thirdPartyId on a table just to be sure.

Comment: thanks for your help, you were on the right track, the where clause was messed up because of the stupid default in C# Oracle!